# JavaScript asyncronous callback error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, asynccallback

I have a question regarding callbacks, errors and asynchronous functions.
Below we have an example of an asynchronous JS callback that handles errors if there are any. Otherwise it does something with the object received.

```
doSomething(aThing, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    return handleError(error);
  } else if (response) {
    return doSomething;
  }
});
```

I imagine that, if there is an error, one of the parameters is an error object and the other one is `null` or `undefined`.

My question is: How does the anonymous callback `function (function(error, response){...})` know that the error parameter is actually an error? What if the callback function would be `function(response, error){...}` ?

Comment: You need to ensure this coordination is correct. JS is dynamically typed, so this is not checked for you, therefore you need to make sure you're using any API properly. So for example, if you're using a 3rd party API, and it receives a callback to handle errors, it's your responsibility to read the documentation and to know exactly what you should pass for the callback. And the creator of that API needs to make sure that the callback is only called in a manner described in the documentation.

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot squint. So basically it could change depending on the API and some could be passing the error on the first parameter and some others on the second.  In Node they have agreed to pass the error on the first parameter as the standad.

Comment: That's right. Because there's no static type checking, documentation of an API is extremely important. A responsible development team will thoroughly document the behavior of their API and will guarantee that the documented behavior will not change. When the team decides that a breaking change is needed, they'll give a deprecation notice for a period of time before introducing the change. So yes, you need write your code to follow the API you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a common pattern used in NodeJS: [**Error First Callback**](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/)

basically, each callback should be called with at least one parameter that indicates wherever there are errors or not...

So, if the first parameter is `null` you can assume that there are no errors...

```js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile("somefile.txt", function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('We have some error', err);
    return;
  }
  
  //do something with your data
  console.log('success', data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't know that it is an error, it would just comeback as null or undefined as you said. Usually you get an error if you are trying to use something that is undefined but you expected it to be defined from the data pull..

a way you could handle the errors is if the data you are pulling from comes up as undefined or null
ie..

```
if (data.response === undefined || data.response === null){
define error
}
if (error) {do something}
```